# Making a numbered dropdown menu's value correspond with a button? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, button

I have successfully coded a button that uses values from an array to generate a random result. But now I need to get whatever value is selected in the above dropdown menu to correspond with the button, and its onClick functions.

Ideally, the whole thing would look like this:

How Many Recruits? [Dropdown Menu from 1 to 150]
Get Recruits! [Button]
(On Pressing the button, you would get a number of recruits equal to whatever value was selected in the dropdown menu.

I've been working on this for days, and even talked to other people about it, but they all said "just use PHP." I want to give Javascript one last shot here (namely because, even though they're similar, I don't want to learn a whole new language just for this project).

Your help will not go unappreciated!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang ="en">

    <!--


    Author's Name
    Current Date
    Name of Site and Page

    Other necessary comments or notes.


    -->

     <head>

     <script>

        var recruit_dropdown = 0 ;
        var morale = 3 ;
        var discipline = 3 ;
        var skill = 1 ;


      function postmessage() {
       var firstnames = ["John", "Jacob", "Eric", "Conroy", "Vincent",     "Laurence", "Jack", "Harry", "Richard", "Michael", "Kevin", "Daniel", "Cody",     "Brody", "Chase", "Cash", "Norman", "Trevor", "Todd", "Ellis", "Quentin", "Zachary", "Bruce", "Sam", "Horace", "George", "Tom", "Tim", "Wallace", "Walter", "Alex", "Alan", "Sean", "Seamus", "Dudley", "Duke", "Damian", "Nash", "Horton", "Robert", "Mitchell", "Ronald", "Ranald", "Donald", "Dick", "Louis", "Charles", "Ezekiel", "Colin", "Collin", "Victor", "Gerald", "Gerard", "Jann", "Hans", "Fritz", "Peter", "Jessie", "Hector", "Homer", "Bob", "Bobby", "Bill", "Duncan", "Dougan", "Ceric", "William", "Xavier", "Hannes", "Theo", "Theobald", "Leo", "Leonard", "Noah", "Liam", "Mason", "Ethan", "Logan", "Aidan", "Benjamin", "Matthew", "Lance", "Lucas", "Luke", "Joseph", "Gabriel", "Gabe", "Gordon", "Joseph", "Stephen", "Steve", "Anthony", "Andrew", "Samuel", "Carter", "Joshua", "Isaac", "Oliver", "Ollifer", "Olly", "Sebastian", "Caleb", "Owen", "Nathan", "Wyatt", "Hunter", "Dylan", "Christopher", "Christian", "Crispin", "Landon", "Jaxon", "Julian", "Jules", "Ryan", "Henry", "Jonathan", "Aaron", "Isaiah", "Thomas", "Jordan", "Conner", "Evan", "Adrian", "Jeremiah", "Eli", "Cameron", "Braydon", "Constantine", "Gavin", "Conor", "Colton", "Angel", "Grayson", "Lance", "Josiah", "Dominic", "Donny", "Ayden", "Tyler", "Parker", "Ian", "Jose", "Ike", "Mitchie", "Mickey", "Mick", "Nolan", "Noland", "Lincoln", "Bentley", "Jayden", "Kayden", "Carson", "Asher", "Nathaniel", "Ryder", "Justin", "Elias", "Camden", "Jase", "Luis", "Jace", "Tristan", "Trist", "Maxwell", "Miles", "Mateo", "Micah", "Damion", "Damios", "Lanse", "Max", "Ronnic", "Roy", "Ronnie", "Ron", "Cole", "Carlos", "Sawyer", "Cutter", "Kaiden", "Braxton", "Bryce", "Ivan", "Wesley", "Axel", "Kaleb", "Ryker", "Rykard", "Ricard", "Joel", "Grant", "Preston", "Bryan", "Bryab", "Briab", "Bryab", "Briar", "Jacques", "Jaqs", "Jaq", "Jag", "Ashton", "Hayden", "Hunt", "Hant", "Patrick", "Marcus", "Aljehandro", "Edward", "King", "Maddox", "Payton", "Emmanuel", "Mannie", "Bennett", "Everett", "Evon", "Brion", "Brian", "Kaden", "Kadyn", "Riley", "Kai", "Kyle", "Stanley", "Stan", "Calvin", "Luca", "Zayden", "Zay", "Mark", "Jake", "Maximus", "Maximillion", "Kenneth", "Ken", "Nicolas", "Paul", "Dereck", "Deric", "Derick", "Donnie", "Don", "Doniel", "Tanner", "Jax", "Zander", "Jorge", "Francis", "Francois", "Maverick", "Mavin", "Gavin", "Omar", "Atlas", "Orrence", "Orince", "Corbin", "Gage", "Graham", "Grahmn", "Gage", "Caden", "Cayden", "Carter", "Jayceon", "Gael", "Gale", "Gunther", "Butch", "Javier", "Iker", "Elliot", "Lukas", "Gunner", "Garett", "Simon", "Francisco", "Rowan", "Keegan", "Finn", "Judah", "Ricardo", "Paxtin", "Martin", "Paxton", "Jefferey", "Jeffry", "Jeff", "Jeffri", "Jonah", "Erick", "Rick", "Eduardo", "Mack", "Mac", "Dallas", "Romeo", "Tony", "Joey", "Cristian", "Troy", "Shane", "Kameron", "Andy", "Tyson", "Tyler", "Tiler", "Tilyr", "Titus", "Nox", "Theod", "Theon", "Lorry", "Lonny", "Lon", "Lonn", "Knox", "Donovan", "Novan", "Andy", "Emilio", "Cruz", "Cruise", "Rafael", "Holden", "Rivyn", "Riven", "Rivven", "Lane", "Landen", "Jared", "Jonothor", "Reginhard", "Reginald", "Reggie", "Sieghard", "Siegfried", "Zain", "Fritt", "Lumis", "AJ", "Wake", "Elliot", "Archie", "Ron", "Grover", "Fritter", "Frits", "Fritts", "Jordan", "Ozzy", "Jordayne", "Amory", "Amoury", "Blaine", "Jazz", "Moshe", "Tant", "Scott", "Brus", "Devin", "Jean", "Dustin", "Chester", "Ragnar", "Hrodeck", "Harold", "Knut", "Cnut", "Tiernan", "Dwayne", "Kiernan", "Jonny", "Jhonny", "Jhonathan", "Jobeck", "Zeke", "Zatch", "Boris", "Vincenzio", "Ivar", "Grick", "Egil", "Egon", "Egor", "Joffrey", "Guy", "Gui", "Pierre", "Peris", "Pike", "Verik", "Ceric", "Dougan", "Siggurd", "Salver", "Nigel", "Kobe", "Carl", "Karl", "Vynjar", "Homer", "Jasper", "Gerard", "Halvin", "Gared", "Galvin", "Toby", "Gordon", "Gallan", "Flash", "Thorin", "Godric", "Godwin", "Gaspar", "Gaston", "Gary", "Hector", "Ralph", "Boyd", "Zimmer", "Anton", "Walder", "Ned", "Mace", "Grick", "Ashley", "Amber", "Alexis", "Amy", "Anna", "Anatasia", "Aines", "Agnes", "Audrey", "Ava", "Ashara", "Annabelle", "Andrea", "Arissa", "Anara", "Agatha", "Alice", "Becky", "Bethany", "Britney", "Betty", "Belle", "Bella", "Beatrice", "Beatrix", "Bea", "Carol", "Cindy", "Courtney", "Cara", "Candy", "Coraline", "Cera", "Constance", "Coraline", "Corra", "Cecily", "Cherry", "Dina", "Diane", "Darla", "Dixie", "Dalilah", "Danielle", "Dillion", "Defina", "Eva", "Eve", "Eliza", "Elizabeth", "Elena", "Ellia", "Ella", "Esmerelda", "Ellen", "Ebbie", "Eufemia", "Ellise", "Fiona", "Flora", "Fae", "Faith", "Gina", "Gala", "Gilly", "Helen", "Hannah", "Hanna", "Harrah", "Harra", "Hope", "Hayley", "Hillary", "Hannabelle", "Hannabella", "Hera", "Hisha", "Herelda", "Ira", "Iva", "Ivy", "Inga", "Jane", "Jill", "Jasmine", "Judie", "Julia", "Julie", "Josie", "Jodie", "Joan", "Jonella", "Kellie", "Kellen", "Katie", "Lola", "Lila", "Lily", "Lillian", "Lindsey", "Lisa", "Lisha", "Lauren", "Laura", "Lina", "Lana", "Luna", "Libby", "Lexi", "Lynessa", "Lois", "Lizzy", "Milly", "Mellisa", "Mona", "Mipsy", "Maddie", "Maple", "Mabin", "Melvina", "Mildred", "Nina", "Nora", "Nona", "Natasha", "Nancy", "Nancie", "Nimmisa", "Olga", "Onah", "Olenda", "Olenna", "Phoebe", "Patty", "Pita", "Rhonda", "Rheece", "Rita", "Sarah", "Suzy", "Suzie", "Sara", "Sena", "Sasha", "Sylvia", "Sora", "Saphira", "Sophie", "Sofie", "Sophia", "Tracy", "Tracie", "Tammy", "Tilly", "Tammy", "Trixie", "Tiffany", "Tia", "Usina", "Uva", "Unara", "Vixie", "Valerie", "Vanessa", "Victoria", "Vera", "Vicky", "Vina", "Wynafryd", "Wila", "Winny", "Whitney", "Xena", "Zoey" ];
   var firstname = firstnames[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstnames.length)];
   var lastnames = [" Ashton", " Ashberry", " Alltimer", " Antlers", " Acheley", " Ashbury", " Abbey", " Abbot", " Abel", " Abney", " Abraham", " Abrahamson", " Abrams", " Abramsson", " Acker", " Ackerman", " Adari", " Adair", " Adamson", " Adams", " Adkins", " Aikens", " Adsworth", " Ainsworth", " Aiken", " Aitken", " Acker", " Ackerman", " Albert", " Albertson", " Albin", " Albinson", " Alexander", " Allard", " Alfredson", " Alfreds", " Allsopp", " Andrews", " Anderson", " Anders", " Ansel", " Anson", " Appleby", " Archer", " Arkstead", " Atkins", " Arnolds", " Arrington", " Attwater", " Audley", " Augustine", " Auttenberry", " Avery", " Ayers", " Averill", " Ayton", " Auttenberg", " Autumns", " Alfson", " Alvery", " Arking", " Arkins", " Aceling", " Antlers", " Adwyn", " Aquinne", " Axington", " Agronn", " Auring", " Autrunter", " Aprunsy", " Avine", " Ammop", " Addlebraum", " Babcock", " Badcoke", " Bagley", " Baines", " Bayley", " Bernardson", " Bernards", " Benedett", " Baker", " Bottle", " Bigby", " Bolton", " Baldwin", " Bancroft", " Bannister", " Booles", " Banks", " Banner", " Bannerman", " Barber", " Bardsley", " Bainer", " Buckwin", " Buller", " Barnes", " Barnet", " Barett", " Barton", " Bass", " Bates", " Bayton", " Batts", " Baxtor", " Beasley", " Beattie", " Becker", " Beckhett", " Benjamins", " Bickley", " Bickers", " Beaumont", " Blanchett", " Blanche", " Beringer", " Blaise", " Bissette", " Bordelon", " Bouchard", " Bruntley", " Bayer", " Bays", " Butler", " Bunting", " Bottley", " Benson", " Belamy", " Buttons", " Berry", " Beverly", " Byrd", " Bishop", " Blackbourne", " Black", " Benton", " Balke", " Blakeson", " Bloke", " Bloodworth", " Broxham", " Bloxam", " Binion", " Burwick", " Boshley", " Bitner", " Bunker", " Bholder", " Baventer", " Bovving", " Bollivers", " Beyder", " Bewer", " Bastionson", " Buckwell", " Borne", " Baverty", " Blackbull", " Baxter", " Buchanan", " Boone", " Bevvil", " Bolly", " Bixtner", " Blackwood", " Bolvin", " Bonham", " Bonner", " Broxx", " Bradford", " Bowman", " Boyce", " Breckenridge", " Brigham", " Bristol", " Broadbrent", " Bryson", " Burke", " Broadham", " Burns", " Burrell", " Broker", " Brittle", " Brittly", " Bosker", " Boxer", " Buckler", " Bickle", " Bamberg", " Bikner", " Carlyle", " Carman", " Cantrell", " Cannon", " Carver", " Cartmann", " Caulfield", " Causer", " Causey", " Chadwick", " Chasset", " Chamberlain", " Chambers", " Chesire", " Church", " Clay", " Clarkson", " Clayton", " Clemens", " Clifford", " Clentin", " Clentlock", " Clent", " Close", " Cockburn", " Cokes", " Cloutier", " Comtois", " Chastain", " Chevalier", " Cutler", " Colbert", " Collins", " Comb", " Comstock", " Conntley", " Constable", " Cooke", " Cooper", " Culler", " Cinch", " Caverty", " Cornell", " Corra", " Cotterill", " Cowden", " Crawford", " Cross", " Cullen", " Crouch", " Candler", " Cummins", " Curtley", " Chasterly", " Chanter", " Corbray", " Colliver", " Crawford", " Crocking"," Dabney", " Dalton", " Dane", " Danell", " Daniels", " Danielson", " Darby", " Darrell", " Durwell", " Duncanson", " Delacroix", " Darwin", " Devinson", " Doland", " Ditcher", " Dickson", " Deforest", " Diecast", " Dupont", " Dixson", " Evers", " Everson", " Evens", " Enicks", " Everlight", " Egonson", " Egilston", " Ericson", " Errister", " Ergonter", " Ebney", " Ebbers", " Ellonts", " Eastwood", " Eastman", " Eastpacker", " Etner", " Ewers", " Fulton", " Fortunato", " Fuller", " Fixner", " Favours", " Fortune", " Faxton", " Flemming", " Flaverty", " Fillquick", " Filch", " Fontleroy", " Fauxcheux", " Favager", " Favrey", " Faure", " Favreau", " Fournier", " Forestter", " Foss", " Fauste", " Fibber", " Foster", " Fletcher", " Fetcher", " Franklins", " Freyer", " Foote", " Flicke", " Fickle", " Gallant", " Gordonson", " Grande", " Gallop", " Gavelthorpe", " Gustavus", " Gillman", " Giver", " Gust", " Guntherson", " Gaper", " Gricksson", " Givner", " Haftner", " Hjort", " Holgerson", " Hilmarson", " Henrikson", " Haugen", " Hotchkiss", " Hogen", " Heathe", " Hansen", " Hall", " Ikross", " Ingolfson", " Ibsen", " Ingersson", " Johnston", " Jameson", " Johanson", " Jensen", " Jones", " Jakeson", " Jenkins", " Jitters", " Killkner", " Krafter", " Karlson", " Kjeldsen", " Kipper", " Kolby", " Kicker", " Klausen", " Knudson", " Kron", " Lionheart", " Lovett", " Libram", " Leake", " Longman", " Lincoln", " Laker", " Leifson", " Libertus", " Lindberg", " Leonardsson", " Ludvigsson", " Luppin", " Lothbrok", " Littel", " Loomer", " Lovegood", " Lafferty", " Lunaberg", " Londotter", " Lyrams", " Lillybade", " Logans", " Luxberg", " Muller", " Makewell", " Mullendore", " Mixxer", " Morner", " Melbourne", " Mopper", " Nemitz", " Noldan", " Nolandson", " Nomer", " Nixton", " North", " Nailer", " Nickers", " Nahn", " Nohr", " Nilson", " Nacker", " Needey", " Nedson", " Nokker", " Nerty", " Nescker", " Nuquill", " Nazz", " Nuppin", " Nolander", " Nevers", " Nohb", " Ottle", " Oldmann", " Olafson", " Oak", " Oatman", " Ovenstone", " Overton", " Osario", " Opender", " Oddley", " Owens", " Omens", " Oracle", " Ozz", " Ossinder", " Osborne", " Puller", " Pfizer", " Piltner", " Packer", " Poseur", " Pillman", " Paver", " Paxter", " Pitcher", " Pickney", " Picketton", " Paster", " Pitney", " Pines", " Prescott", " Proctor", " Perwynn", " Payne", " Poshe", " Pyre", " Prick", " Quarterman", " Quilter", " Quinn", " Quick", " Quartzman", " Quail", " Ryan", " Rallant", " Rollander", " Rickardson", " Rivetter", " Rickney", " Raverty", " Ranaldson", " Rykerr", " Riggerman", " Reacher", " Rhodahl", " Rower", " Rester", " Royson", " Ripley", " Rifter", " Rafter", " Rustt", " Roper", " Riddick", " Rastton", " Rouen", " Rosegrower", " Roberts", " Rijitt", " Roamer", " Ruyton", " Razner", " Rohe", " Reeces", " Reinhardt", " Rutger", " Reiter", " Reityer", " Sutcliffe", " Stintson", " Stantson", " Stotch", " Stillman", " Stopper", " Stanric", " Stoland", " Spencer", " Stoickson", " Stark", " Stake", " Simmers", " Simmonson", " Sissinius", " Stohlman", " Stickler", " Stewer", " Sapper", " Sawmann", " Sawyers", " Stipper", " Stackhouse", " Slacksley", " Stern", " Shett", " Shivv", " Spinner", " Spitz", " Spaffer", " Sugsley", " Sluys", " Slugger", " Simpleton", " Savinnce", " Salendo", " Sania", " Siggurdson", " Siwir", " Sodder", " Stageman", " Sissilio", " Summers", " Springs", " Stump", " Seraph", " Singer", " Sandalwine", " Salvenson", " Scrivner", " Topper", " Tinker", " Troute", " Trillby", " Tasker", " Thompson", " Traye", " Trolliver", " Tranke", " Trusty", " Truman", " Tartt", " Tanner", " Tang", " Taft", " Totch", " Trodder", " Treviso", " Ullin", " Vonter", " Villian", " Vixxen", " Viviers", " Villiers", " Vonnegutt", " Vickers", " Viewer", " Vake", " Vitner", " Vindercourt", " Valliance", " Wylde", " Wibley", " Wonders", " Wicker", " Wynafryds", " Wilder", " Wollander", " Wincher", " Wallaby", " Wann", " Wittle", " Witcher", " Williamson", " Welder", " Westlander", " Winters", " Wiseman", " Williker", " Woolter", " Wivner", " Wipple", " Werton", " Wordsworth", " Wintercane", " Wulquix", " Wigg", " Willums", " Willows", " Webber", " Winger", " Wiqquer", " Wadd", " Wooler", " Welsh", " Walsh", " Welcher", " Welch", " Xavianos", " Yarwick", " Yolander", " Yilstringer", " Yeller", " Zieglar", " Zimmerman", " Zapp", " Zanderson" ];
   var lastname = lastnames[Math.floor(Math.random() * lastnames.length) ];
   var ages = [", age 16.", ", age 17.", ", age 18.", ", age 19.", ", age 20.", ", age 21.", ", age 22.", ", age 23.", ", age 24.", ", age 25.", ", age 26.", ", age 27.", ", age 28.", ", age 29.", ", age 30.", ", age 31.", ", age 32.", ", age 33.", ", age 34.", ", age 35." ] ;
   var age = ages[Math.floor(Math.random() * ages.length) ];
   var personalities = [" They have a Cruel personality (-1 Discipline, +1 Morale, increased chance for infighting).", " They have an Arrogant personality (-2 Discipline, +1 Morale).", " They have an Arrogant personality (-2 Discipline, +1 Morale).", " They have an Arrogant personality (-2 Discipline, +1 Morale).", " They have an Aloof personality (No effect).", " They have an Aloof personality (No effect).", " They have an Aloof personality (No effect).", " They have a Melancholic personality (-1 Morale, will never engage in infighting).", " They have a Melancholic personality (-1 Morale, will never engage in infighting).", " They have a Meek personality (-1 Morale, +1 Discipline, increased chance of being victim of infighting).", " They have a Meek personality (-1 Morale, +1 Discipline, increased chance of being victim of infighting).", " They have a Rowdy personality (+1 Morale, -2 Discipline).", " They have a Rowdy personality (+1 Morale, -2 Discipline).", " They have an Insane personality (-3 Discipline, Unpredictable)." ] ;
   var personality = personalities[Math.floor(Math.random() * personalities.length) ];
   document.getElementById("recruit1").textContent = "Your new recruit is Pvt. " + firstname + lastname + age + personality ;

}
   function postmorale() {
   document.getElementById("recruit2").textContent = "Morale: " + morale ;
   } 
   function postdiscipline() {
   document.getElementById("recruit3").textContent = "Discipline: " + discipline ;
   }
   function postskill() {
   document.getElementById("recruit4").textContent = "Skill: " + skill ;
   }

  </script>

  <title>TitleOfSite</title>
  <meta charset = "utf-8" >
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="whatever-your-stylesheet-is-named.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="whatever-your-site's-icon-is-named.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>

  <!-- [if lt IE 9 ]>
  <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
  <![endif]-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

 </head>

 <body>
  <form>
          <legend>Get</legend>
             <select id = "dropdown">
               <option value = "1">1</option>
               <option value = "2">2</option>
               <option value = "3">3</option>
               <option value = "4">4</option>
               <option value = "5">5</option>
               <option value = "6">6</option>
               <option value = "7">7</option>
               <option value = "8">8</option>
               <option value = "9">9</option>
               <option value = "10">10</option>
               <option value = "11">11</option>
               <option value = "12">12</option>
               <option value = "13">13</option>
               <option value = "14">14</option>
               <option value = "15">15</option>
               <option value = "16">16</option>
               <option value = "17">17</option>
               <option value = "18">18</option>
               <option value = "19">19</option>
               <option value = "20">20</option>
               <option value = "21">21</option>
               <option value = "22">22</option>
               <option value = "23">23</option>
               <option value = "24">24</option>
               <option value = "25">25</option>
               <option value = "26">26</option>
               <option value = "27">27</option>
               <option value = "28">28</option>
               <option value = "29">29</option>
               <option value = "30">30</option>
               <option value = "31">31</option>
               <option value = "32">32</option>
               <option value = "33">33</option>
               <option value = "34">34</option>
               <option value = "35">35</option>
               <option value = "36">36</option>
               <option value = "37">37</option>
               <option value = "38">38</option>
               <option value = "39">39</option>
               <option value = "40">40</option>
               <option value = "41">41</option>
               <option value = "42">42</option>
               <option value = "43">43</option>
               <option value = "44">44</option>
               <option value = "45">45</option>
               <option value = "46">46</option>
               <option value = "47">47</option>
               <option value = "48">48</option>
               <option value = "49">49</option>
               <option value = "50">50</option>
               <option value = "51">51</option>
               <option value = "52">52</option>
               <option value = "53">53</option>
               <option value = "54">54</option>
               <option value = "55">55</option>
               <option value = "56">56</option>
               <option value = "57">57</option>
               <option value = "58">58</option>
               <option value = "59">59</option>
               <option value = "60">60</option>
               <option value = "61">61</option>
               <option value = "62">62</option>
               <option value = "63">63</option>
               <option value = "64">64</option>
               <option value = "65">65</option>
               <option value = "66">66</option>
               <option value = "67">67</option>
               <option value = "68">68</option>
               <option value = "69">69</option>
               <option value = "70">70</option>
               <option value = "71">71</option>
               <option value = "72">72</option>
               <option value = "73">73</option>
               <option value = "74">74</option>
               <option value = "75">75</option>
               <option value = "76">76</option>
               <option value = "77">77</option>
               <option value = "78">78</option>
               <option value = "79">79</option>
               <option value = "80">80</option>
               <option value = "81">81</option>
               <option value = "82">82</option>
               <option value = "83">83</option>
               <option value = "84">84</option>
               <option value = "85">85</option>
               <option value = "86">86</option>
               <option value = "87">87</option>
               <option value = "88">88</option>
               <option value = "89">89</option>
               <option value = "90">90</option>
               <option value = "91">91</option>
               <option value = "92">92</option>
               <option value = "93">93</option>
               <option value = "94">94</option>
               <option value = "95">95</option>
               <option value = "96">96</option>
               <option value = "97">97</option>
               <option value = "98">98</option>
               <option value = "99">99</option>
               <option value = "100">100</option>
               <option value = "101">101</option>
               <option value = "102">102</option>
               <option value = "102">102</option>
               <option value = "103">103</option>
               <option value = "104">104</option>
               <option value = "105">105</option>
               <option value = "106">106</option>
               <option value = "107">107</option>
               <option value = "108">108</option>
               <option value = "109">109</option>
               <option value = "110">110</option>
               <option value = "111">111</option>
               <option value = "112">112</option>
               <option value = "113">113</option>
               <option value = "114">114</option>
               <option value = "115">115</option>
               <option value = "116">116</option>
               <option value = "117">117</option>
               <option value = "118">118</option>
               <option value = "119">119</option>
               <option value = "120">120</option>
               <option value = "121">121</option>
               <option value = "122">122</option>
               <option value = "123">123</option>
               <option value = "124">124</option>
               <option value = "125">125</option>
               <option value = "126">126</option>
               <option value = "127">127</option>
               <option value = "128">128</option>
               <option value = "129">129</option>
               <option value = "130">130</option>
               <option value = "131">131</option>
               <option value = "132">132</option>
               <option value = "133">133</option>
               <option value = "134">134</option>
               <option value = "135">135</option>
               <option value = "136">136</option>
               <option value = "137">137</option>
               <option value = "138">138</option>
               <option value = "139">139</option>
               <option value = "140">140</option>
               <option value = "141">141</option>
               <option value = "142">142</option>
               <option value = "143">143</option>
               <option value = "144">144</option>
               <option value = "145">145</option>
               <option value = "146">146</option>
               <option value = "147">147</option>
               <option value = "148">148</option>
               <option value = "149">149</option>
               <option value = "150">150</option>
             </select>
    </form>
  <input type="button" value="Get Recruit" onclick="postmessage(); postmorale(); postdiscipline(); postskill();" />
  <div id="recruit1"></div>
  <div id="recruit2"></div>
  <div id="recruit3"></div>
  <div id="recruit4"></div>
 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need PHP for this ... in fact, that's the wrong computer altogether (the host, vs. the client machine).

What you need to do is to attach an event to the list's *onChange* event. When the value changes, retrieve the value. Then, post a *click*-event to the button, which it will react to exactly as if it the pseudo-click had come from the browser.

Comment: Going to give this a shot when I get home. Thank you!